# Given $a,b_0,\ldots,b_n$, there exists a polynomial of degree $\le n$ s.t. the derivatives $f^{(i)}(a)=b_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

Just exploring some maths problems from a book until I came across this question.

Let $a, b_0, . . . , b_n ∈ R$. Show that there exists a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree at most n such that
$$f(a) = b_0, f'
(a) = b_1, f''(a) = b_2,\ldots , f^{(n)}
(a) = b_n$$

I am not sure how to approach this problem, can someone give me a guide of how to do this problem?

Comment: Consider writing $f(x)$ as $\sum\limits_{i=0}^nc_n(x-a)^n$

Comment: I'm unsure about what the question is asking, what am I supposed to find?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general polynomial of degree $n$

$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots a_nx^n
$$

Since we know that a polynomial is uniquely determined by its [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)
, consider the taylor expansion of $f(x)$ about $a$, which is

$$
f(x) = f(a) + \frac{(x - a)f'(a)}{1!} + \frac{(x - a)^2f''(a)}{2!} + \ldots \frac{(x - a)^nf^n(x)}{n!}
$$

which gives us the unique polynomial in terms of the derivatives at $a$ and powers of $(x - a)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following polynomial:

$$ p(x) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{b_i}{i!}(x-a)^i $$

And observe that:

$p^{(k)}(a) = \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} 0\right) + \sum\limits_{i=k}^n\frac{b_i}{(i-k)!}(x-a)^{i-k} = b_k $

Answer (score 0):

I'll show it for a cubic polynomial, let $f(x)=px^3+qx^2+rx+s$.

Expressing the given constraints, we have

$$\begin{cases}f(a)&=pa^3+qa^2+ra+s\\f'(a)&=3pa^2+2qa+r\\f''(a)&=6pa+2q\\f'''(a)&=6p.\end{cases}$$

This is a system of linear equations in triangular form, which can be readily solved.

$$\begin{cases}p=\frac16f'''(a)\\q=\frac12(f''(a)-6pa)\\r=f'(a)-3pa^2-2qa\\s=f(a)-pa^3-qa^2-ra.\end{cases}$$

As the diagonal coefficients are never zero, a solution is always guaranteed. You can generalize for any degree.

Comment: Can I ask what a 'diagonal coefficient is?

Comment: The coefficients on the oblique side of the triangle.

Comment: How would you show that the coefficients are never zero?

Comment: @ArthurKingLee: Can $6$ ever be zero ?